# jquery .live('click',function(event) work only once when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am using jquery dialog in which i put 2 textbox and 1 button. Which works fine, everything renders. On button in dialog I am appling validation on my textbox if its empty. So the validation work fine for the first time when page renders but  not working after that on another dialog.
Have a look at my both function.
The first one is for dialog ,second is for updating  the textbox in dialog

```
$('.update_service_name').live('click',function(event){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var old_value        = $tr.children('td:eq(1)').text(),
        phone_service_id = $tr.children('td:eq(2)').text();
    var old_value_textbox = "<div class='learfix'><label>Current Service Name</label><div class='input'><input class='large' type='text' value='"+old_value+"' disabled='disabled'/></div></div>" ;
    var new_value_textbox ="<div class='learfix' id='div_new_value'><label>New Service Name</label><div class='input'><input class='large' type='text' value='' id='new_service_name' /><span class='help' id='error_message_div_new_value'></span></div></div>";
    var update_button ="<span><span class='update_service_name_btn'><a href='#' class='small blue button'><span>Update</span></a></span> <img src='"+ temp_images_path +"/small_loader.gif' id='small_loader' style='display:none;float:right;margin: 3px 150px 0 0;' /></span>" ;

    var $dialog = $('<div>',{title:'Update Service Name'}).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 250
    });

    $('<p>').html(old_value_textbox).appendTo($dialog);
    $('<p>').html(new_value_textbox).appendTo($dialog);
    $('<p>').html(update_button).appendTo($dialog);

    $dialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Validating the textbox in dialog

```
$('.update_service_name_btn').live('click',function(event){
    var pass = true;
    var new_service_name = $("#new_service_name").val();
    $("#error_message_div_new_value").html(' ');

    if(!new_service_name){
        $("#error_message_div_new_value").html('New Serrvice Name Please!');
        pass = false;
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Updated**

```
$('.update_service_name').live('click',function(event){
 var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
 var old_value        = $tr.children('td:eq(1)').text(),
phone_service_id = $tr.children('td:eq(2)').text();
  var old_value_textbox = "<div class='learfix'><label>Current Service Name</label><div class='input'><input class='large' type='text' value='"+old_value+"' disabled='disabled'/></div></div>" ;
 var new_value_textbox ="<div class='learfix' id='div_new_value'><label>New Service Name</label><div class='input'><input class='large' type='text' value='' id='new_service_name' /><span class='help' id='error_message_div_new_value'></span></div></div>";
 var $update_button = $("<span><span class='update_service_name_btn'><a href='#' class='small blue button'><span>Update</span></a></span> <img src='"+ temp_images_path +"/small_loader.gif' id='small_loader' style='display:none;float:right;margin: 3px 150px 0 0;' /></span>");

 $update_button.find('.update_service_name_btn').live('click',function(event){
   var pass = true;
  var new_service_name = $("#new_service_name").val();
  $("#error_message_div_new_value").html(' ');
  if(!new_service_name){
    $("#error_message_div_new_value").html('New Serrvice Name Please!');
    pass = false;
    return false;
  }
 });

 var $dialog = $('<div>',{title:'Update Service Name'}).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
    width: 250
 });

 $('<p>').html(old_value_textbox).appendTo($dialog);
 $('<p>').html(new_value_textbox).appendTo($dialog);
 $('<p>').append($update_button).appendTo($dialog);

 $dialog.dialog('open');
 return false;
});
```

Validating the textbox in dialog(remain same as old)

```
 $('.update_service_name_btn').live('click',function(event){
var pass = true;
var new_service_name = $("#new_service_name").val();
$("#error_message_div_new_value").html(' ');

if(!new_service_name){
    $("#error_message_div_new_value").html('New Serrvice Name Please!');
    pass = false;
    return false;
}
});
```

plz **Notice**
i just figured out that the whole problem is in my dynamically creating text box.i alerted the value of text box and at the first click it alert the correct value and after that with each alert i mean with new dialog i am getting the old text box value that is the first one i entered.can any please help me how to get solve this issue ???

Comment: Does console throw any error ?

Comment: What is the purpose of pass variable? You define it in as a local one and do not use

Comment: yes its local and i ll use it for ajax request that is if pass == true make ajax request other wise dont make ajax request

Comment: So, Teknords, the problem lies in the second code - it doesn't run the second time ? console.log() the values and look at them. Maybe something in your DOM has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do so & i am sure you problem will be solved

```
var $dialog=null;
$('.update_service_name').live('click',function(event){
if($dialog!=null){
$dialog.remove();
}
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var old_value        = $tr.children('td:eq(1)').text(),
phone_service_id = $tr.children('td:eq(2)').text();
var old_value_textbox = "<div class='learfix'><label>Current Service Name</label><div class='input'><input class='large' type='text' value='"+old_value+"' disabled='disabled'/></div></div>" ;
var new_value_textbox ="<div class='clearfix'><label>New Service Name</label><div class='input'><input class='large' type='text' value='' id='new_service_name' /><span class='help' id='error_message_div_new_value'></span></div></div>";
var $update_button = $("<span><span class='update_service_name_btn'><a href='#' class='small blue button'><span>Update</span></a></span> <img src='"+ temp_images_path +"/small_loader.gif' id='small_loader' style='display:none;float:right;margin: 3px 150px 0 0;' /></span>");
$dialog = $('<div>',{title:'Update Service Name'}).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 250
 });

$('<p>').html(old_value_textbox).appendTo($dialog);
$('<p>').html(new_value_textbox).appendTo($dialog);
$('<p>').append($update_button).appendTo($dialog);

  $dialog.dialog('open');
return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to  run your validation code for each time you recreate your dialog. Now the event is getting registered only once, then for the next time you open the dialog, a new `update_service_name_btn` is created but you do not register the event again!
For example:

```
...
var $update_button = $("<span><span class='update_service_name_btn'><a href='#' class='small blue button'><span>Update</span></a></span> <img src='"+ temp_images_path +"/small_loader.gif' id='small_loader' style='display:none;float:right;margin: 3px 150px 0 0;' /></span>");
$update_button.find('.update_service_name_btn').live('click',function(event){
  var pass = true;
  var new_service_name = $("#new_service_name").val();
  $("#error_message_div_new_value").html(' ');
  if(!new_service_name){
    $("#error_message_div_new_value").html('New Serrvice Name Please!');
    pass = false;
    return false;
  }
});    

var $dialog = ...
...
$('<p>').append($update_button).appendTo($dialog);
...
```

**Full code:**

```
$('.update_service_name').live('click',function(event){
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var old_value        = $tr.children('td:eq(1)').text(),
    phone_service_id = $tr.children('td:eq(2)').text();
  var old_value_textbox = "<div class='learfix'><label>Current Service Name</label><div class='input'><input class='large' type='text' value='"+old_value+"' disabled='disabled'/></div></div>" ;
  var new_value_textbox ="<div class='learfix' id='div_new_value'><label>New Service Name</label><div class='input'><input class='large' type='text' value='' id='new_service_name' /><span class='help' id='error_message_div_new_value'></span></div></div>";
  var $update_button = $("<span><span class='update_service_name_btn'><a href='#' class='small blue button'><span>Update</span></a></span> <img src='"+ temp_images_path +"/small_loader.gif' id='small_loader' style='display:none;float:right;margin: 3px 150px 0 0;' /></span>");

  $update_button.find('.update_service_name_btn').live('click',function(event){
    var pass = true;
    var new_service_name = $("#new_service_name").val();
    $("#error_message_div_new_value").html(' ');
    if(!new_service_name){
      $("#error_message_div_new_value").html('New Serrvice Name Please!');
      pass = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  var $dialog = $('<div>',{title:'Update Service Name'}).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 250
  });

  $('<p>').html(old_value_textbox).appendTo($dialog);
  $('<p>').html(new_value_textbox).appendTo($dialog);
  $('<p>').append($update_button).appendTo($dialog);

  $dialog.dialog('open');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: @Teknords check now, was correct in the first code snippet, edited now in second also.

Comment: can i remove my Validating the textbox in dialog function ??

Comment: The above `click` event handler has to be used for the creation of **each** dialog. So if there are multiple dialogs, I guess the `$('.update_service_name')` selector used will not be sufficient.

Comment: so what can i do now ??my code now making event with each creation of dialouge but it fire only once .what to do now ??

Comment: I don't really understand, can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) recreating your problem?

Comment: i dont know sir how to do that if u want me to update my code i ll do so .shall i ??

Comment: go ahead, but be sure to show the different dialog button initializations

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9398/discussion-between-teknords-and-jb10210)